# How to select a certain key from Json string

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am trying to get the value of "accountBalance", but beside of that I get also  a bunch of unwanted "0". It seems that I get  the "0" on every element that has no "accountBalance" key .  How could I select only those elements that contains the key  "accountBalance".

My Code:

```
var resultOpTrades = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);//Deserialize Json
var pricelist = resultOpTrades.transactions.Select(p => p.accountBalance).ToList().Select(s => Convert.ToDouble(s)).ToList();
pricelist.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

JSON:

```
{"transactions": [
{
  "type": "CLIENT_CONFIGURE",
  "marginRate": "0.02",
  "alias": "Test USD",
  "id": "2",
  "userID": 4455670,
  "accountID": "101-004-4455670-004",
  "batchID": "1",
  "requestID": "1789786643428780285",
  "time": "2018-01-22T13:01:57.930423995Z"
},
{
  "accountBalance": "2000.0000",
  "type": "TRANSFER_FUNDS",
  "amount": "2000.0000000000",
  "fundingReason": "ADJUSTMENT",
  "id": "3",
  "userID": 4455670,
  "accountID": "101-004-4455670-004",
  "batchID": "3",
  "requestID": "1735743448013647784",
  "time": "2018-01-22T13:02:24.580177329Z"
},
{
  "type": "MARKET_ORDER",
  "instrument": "EUR_JPY",
  "units": "-2000",
  "timeInForce": "FOK",
  "positionFill": "DEFAULT",
  "reason": "CLIENT_ORDER",
  "id": "4",
  "userID": 4455670,
  "accountID": "101-004-4455670-004",
  "batchID": "4",
  "requestID": "60404387589188847",
  "time": "2018-01-22T13:06:12.138121604Z"
},
{
  "type": "ORDER_FILL",
  "orderID": "4",
  "instrument": "EUR_JPY",
  "units": "-2000",
  "price": "135.627",
  "pl": "0.0000",
  "financing": "0.0000",
  "commission": "0.0000",
  "accountBalance": "2000.0000",
  "gainQuoteHomeConversionFactor": "0.009022013713",
  "lossQuoteHomeConversionFactor": "0.009023071995",
  "guaranteedExecutionFee": "0.0000",
  "halfSpreadCost": "0.1353",
  "fullVWAP": "135.627",
  "reason": "MARKET_ORDER",
  "tradeOpened": {
    "price": "135.627",
    "tradeID": "5",
    "units": "-2000",
    "guaranteedExecutionFee": "0.0000",
    "halfSpreadCost": "0.1353"
  },
  "fullPrice": {
    "closeoutBid": "135.627",
    "closeoutAsk": "135.642",
    "timestamp": "2018-01-22T13:05:56.780436649Z",
    "bids": [
      {
        "price": "135.627",
        "liquidity": "10000000"
      }
    ],
    "asks": [
      {
        "price": "135.642",
        "liquidity": "10000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": "5",
  "userID": 4455670,
  "accountID": "101-004-4455670-004",
  "batchID": "4",
  "requestID": "60404387589188847",
  "time": "2018-01-22T13:06:12.138121604Z"
},
{
  "type": "MARKET_ORDER",
  "instrument": "EUR_JPY",
  "units": "2000",
  "timeInForce": "FOK",
  "positionFill": "REDUCE_ONLY",
  "reason": "TRADE_CLOSE",
  "tradeClose": {
    "units": "ALL",
    "tradeID": "5"
  },
  "id": "6",
  "userID": 4455670,
  "accountID": "101-004-4455670-004",
  "batchID": "6",
  "requestID": "60404387832520278",
  "time": "2018-01-22T13:07:10.544407912Z"
},],"lastTransactionID": "22083"}
```

The result I get:
 0,
2000,
0,
2000,
0,

Comment: What does your RootObject look like?

Comment: It seems like your JSON contains a list of RootObject but some properties are ignored if it is null `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]`. That's why some properties are missing in your JSON item. So you can either check if it is null or zero before using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Json.Linq`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to parse your JSON into [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), then iterate a `transactions` property and get an `accountBalance` values

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(result));
foreach (var item in json["transactions"])
{
    if (item["accountBalance"] != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item["accountBalance"].Value<double>());
    }
}
```

Comment: @DianaM00nshine Welcome, you can approve an answer, if it solves your question:)

Answer (score 0):

Filter the pricelist with the value zero using a `Where` in `Linq`

```cs
var resultOpTrades = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);//Deserialize Json
var pricelist = resultOpTrades.transactions.Where(x => x.accountBalance != 0).Select(p => Convert.ToDouble(p.accountBalance)).ToList();
pricelist.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Diana M00nshine,

From what I understood, you want to take only the transactions that has the accountBalance field set.

First, I would suggest you to create this class to reflect the schema of your json array field called "transactions".

```cs
class Transaction
{
    public string accountBalance { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string marginRate { get; set; }
    public string alias { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public string accountID { get; set; }
    public string batchID { get; set; }
    public string requestID { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}
```

To get all the transactions that have the property accountBalance defined in the JSON string you could do as showed below:

1. Parse the json string
2. Take the transactions token and cast it to an IEnumerable
3. Then for each item inside the transactions token, you convert them to an object of the class Transaction that I have included in the source code above.
4. Cast to a list of Transaction objects

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
List<Transaction> transactionsWithAccountBalance = json["transactions"].AsJEnumerable()
                                                        .Where(t => t["accountBalance"] != null)
                                                        .Select(t => t.ToObject<Transaction>())
                                                        .ToList();
```

If you want only the transactions that not only have the key accountBalance set in the json but also different than null or empty, you could update the where condition as follow

```cs
.Where(t => t["accountBalance"] != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(t["accountBalance"].Value<string>()))
```

Then, if you want a list with all the account balances of your transactions, you could do:

```cs
var priceList = transactionsWithAccountBalance.Select(t => t.accountBalance).ToList();
```

I've included this little test class to let you easily try my solution. You can see the in the list will be present only transactions that have the interested key in the json file set.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonString = @"{
            ""transactions"": [
            {
                ""type"": ""CLIENT_CONFIGURE"",
                ""marginRate"": ""0.02"",
                ""alias"": ""Test USD"",
                ""id"": ""2"",
                ""userID"": 4455670,
                ""accountID"": ""101-004-4455670-004"",
                ""batchID"": ""1"",
                ""requestID"": ""1789786643428780285"",
                ""time"": ""2018-01-22T13:01:57.930423995Z""
            },
            {
                ""accountBalance"": ""2000.0000"",
                ""type"": ""TRANSFER_FUNDS"",
                ""amount"": ""2000.0000000000"",
                ""fundingReason"": ""ADJUSTMENT"",
                ""id"": ""3"",
                ""userID"": 4455670,
                ""accountID"": ""101-004-4455670-004"",
                ""batchID"": ""3"",
                ""requestID"": ""1735743448013647784"",
                ""time"": ""2018-01-22T13:02:24.580177329Z""
            },
            {
                ""type"": ""MARKET_ORDER"",
                ""instrument"": ""EUR_JPY"",
                ""units"": ""-2000"",
                ""timeInForce"": ""FOK"",
                ""positionFill"": ""DEFAULT"",
                ""reason"": ""CLIENT_ORDER"",
                ""id"": ""4"",
                ""userID"": 4455670,
                ""accountID"": ""101-004-4455670-004"",
                ""batchID"": ""4"",
                ""requestID"": ""60404387589188847"",
                ""time"": ""2018-01-22T13:06:12.138121604Z""
            },
            {
                ""type"": ""ORDER_FILL"",
                ""orderID"": ""4"",
                ""instrument"": ""EUR_JPY"",
                ""units"": ""-2000"",
                ""price"": ""135.627"",
                ""pl"": ""0.0000"",
                ""financing"": ""0.0000"",
                ""commission"": ""0.0000"",
                ""accountBalance"": ""2000.0000"",
                ""gainQuoteHomeConversionFactor"": ""0.009022013713"",
                ""lossQuoteHomeConversionFactor"": ""0.009023071995"",
                ""guaranteedExecutionFee"": ""0.0000"",
                ""halfSpreadCost"": ""0.1353"",
                ""fullVWAP"": ""135.627"",
                ""reason"": ""MARKET_ORDER"",
                ""tradeOpened"": {
                ""price"": ""135.627"",
                ""tradeID"": ""5"",
                ""units"": ""-2000"",
                ""guaranteedExecutionFee"": ""0.0000"",
                ""halfSpreadCost"": ""0.1353""
                },
                ""fullPrice"": {
                ""closeoutBid"": ""135.627"",
                ""closeoutAsk"": ""135.642"",
                ""timestamp"": ""2018-01-22T13:05:56.780436649Z"",
                ""bids"": [
                    {
                    ""price"": ""135.627"",
                    ""liquidity"": ""10000000""
                    }
                ],
                ""asks"": [
                    {
                    ""price"": ""135.642"",
                    ""liquidity"": ""10000000""
                    }
                ]
                },
                ""id"": ""5"",
                ""userID"": 4455670,
                ""accountID"": ""101-004-4455670-004"",
                ""batchID"": ""4"",
                ""requestID"": ""60404387589188847"",
                ""time"": ""2018-01-22T13:06:12.138121604Z""
            },
            {
                ""type"": ""MARKET_ORDER"",
                ""instrument"": ""EUR_JPY"",
                ""units"": ""2000"",
                ""timeInForce"": ""FOK"",
                ""positionFill"": ""REDUCE_ONLY"",
                ""reason"": ""TRADE_CLOSE"",
                ""tradeClose"": {
                ""units"": ""ALL"",
                ""tradeID"": ""5""
                },
                ""id"": ""6"",
                ""userID"": 4455670,
                ""accountID"": ""101-004-4455670-004"",
                ""batchID"": ""6"",
                ""requestID"": ""60404387832520278"",
                ""time"": ""2018-01-22T13:07:10.544407912Z""
            }
            ],
            ""lastTransactionID"": ""22083""
        }";

        var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        List<Transaction> transactionsWithAccountBalance = json["transactions"].AsJEnumerable()
                                                                .Where(t => t["accountBalance"] != null)
                                                                .Select(t => t.ToObject<Transaction>())
                                                                .ToList();

        var priceList = transactionsWithAccountBalance.Select(t => t.accountBalance).ToList();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add these namespaces in order to compile the program class:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thank you. I used Pavel Anikhouski solution